How to insert C-style array into std::unordered_map as value
Is there a way to insert a C-style array into a std::unordered_map as value?
For example, the followings all give compiler error
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map <int, int[2]> testMap;
    int temp[2]{ 0,0 };
    //testMap.insert({ 1, temp });
    //testMap[1] = temp;
    //testMap.insert({1,{0,0}});
    //testMap[1]=int[2]{0,0};
}

Or is it only possible to use a map for std::unordered_map <int, int*>?
I understand that std::array<int,2> would work instead. But I am new to C++ and hoping to understand the behavior of C-style array better.

Why don't you use std::unordered_map<int,std::array<int,2>> this is C++ after all (so let go of your "C" style arrays)

AFAIK the only way to treat a plain old C array "by value" is to have it as a member of a structure. You're much better of by learning to use std::array instead (which basically does that structure wrapping for you). You need to learn it sooner or later anyway, so why not now?

C style array are non-copyable (unless put into a structure as mentioned above). This is why you cannot use them as you attempt. std::array is definitely the way to go here.

Thank you for chiming in. I was going to use std::array on my own for this use case unless I get tips on how to use C-style array which turn out more convenient. So it's not a preference against std::array but more hoping to learn more about how C-style array may work. It seems this is an example where C-style array is not worth exploring?

int temp[2]{ 0,0 }; int temp2[2]; temp2 = temp; -- You don't need to use unordered_map to see that arrays are dumb.  As mentioned, even a simple = doesn't work.

I would still say avoid "C" style arrays if you can. With std::array you have all the benefits of it acting like a class, like easy copying, returning from functions, pass by (const) reference, not losing size info when using it as an argument. No pointer decay etc.. etc..

@PepijnKramer: Thank you for the tips. Initially the main difference that struck me was only there is no pointer decay with std::array which only seemed limiting in some cases. It's only now that I realize the lack of assignment, copying, moving, etc are rather detrimental to productive use of C-style arrays. It's like taking away every tool you want to have. Today I learned. And for that I am glad. Thanks!

you're welcome. If you ever need to do something like "pointer decay" you can still use std::array's data() method

How to use a type array in map in c++ and C-style array in C++ map

Normally, an array type is not a valid type for standard containers because standard containers require their value_type to be Destructible. This means that you can explicitly call obj.~T();, for example to clear the container in the destructor. This isn't supported for arrays, where you have to destroy the elements individually (for (auto& el : obj) el.~std::remove_extent_t<T>(); or std::destroy_at(std::addressof(obj));).
However, for std::unordered_map, the value_type is std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>. This type is destructible, it's just really hard to construct.
You can't create it like std::pair<const int, int[2]>{ 1, temp }, since an array is not (generally) constructible from another array.
You have to do something like this:
std::pair<const int, int[2]> insertion(std::piecewise_construct, std::tuple<int>(1), std::tuple<>());
// pair initialises members like `: first(1), second()`, so second is empty
insertion.second[0] = temp[0]; insertion.second[1] = temp[1];
testMap.insert(insertion);

Or in C++20, where you can use parentheses to initialize aggregates like arrays:
// pair initialises members like `: first(1), second(temp[0], temp[1])`
testMap.insert({ std::piecewise_construct, std::tuple(1), std::tuple(temp[0], temp[1]) });

Copying/moving the value_type does what you expect. std::pair's copy constructor is defaulted, which for array members just copies each element. The only real problem is constructing it in the first place.

Though I would not recommend using a int[2] array. You've seen that having an array as a struct member (like that std::pair's second member) makes it much nicer to work with. You can have that array be a member of another struct, like std::array<int, 2>, which is also copyable and so easier to construct:
std::unordered_map<int, std::array<int, 2>> testMap;
std::array<int, 2> temp{ 0,0 };
testMap.insert({ 1, temp });

